# Date format from Mysql SELECT query

Tags: mysql, date, time

My query is this...

```
SELECT a.ID, a.time, a.quote, a.quantity, a.media, a.print, a.pack 
FROM quotes a
```

It returns my dates like this...

How do I make the results come back as `March 2, 2012` or `05/04/2012` or something meaningful?

UPDATE - FROM_UNIXTIME answers below list all records as having time when I run the query - I need the time the records were originally created - NOT the query time.

Any other ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this function: [FROM_UNIXTIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)

In your case it will be something like this (for first example):

```
SELECT a.ID, FROM_UNIXTIME(a.`time`, '%M %e, %Y'), 
    a.quote, a.quantity, a.media, a.print, a.pack 
FROM quotes a
```

Also what you might want to do is to to give result an alias:

```
SELECT a.ID, FROM_UNIXTIME(a.`time`, '%M %e, %Y') as formatted_time, 
    a.quote, a.quantity, a.media, a.print, a.pack 
FROM quotes a
```

And then you will be accessing result of formating as `formatted_time` not `time`...

NOTICE: Please observe that time column name is in backticks

```
 a.`time`
```

Lac of back ticks caused query to return current time instead of value of time column

Comment: Unfortunately these suggestions list every record as having the same date/time - the time i run the query - not the time the records were created.

Comment: @lowercase: What do you mean by that? This will make every record to have the same date format but the actual date would be dependant on the value of a.time

Comment: I mean I have 500 records - all created on different times and dates, but when i run the above query EVERY date returns the date/time it is right now (the time i run the query).
Given the follwoing options to display - should i run query datatype as 'TEXT', 'DATE', 'TIME', 'DATE+TIME', 'NUMBER', or 'DECIMAL'?

Comment: @lowercase: What does a.time store? Does it store this created time or something else? Not sure what you mean by 'run query datatype as' but if you store timestamp then its a NUMBER

Comment: @lowercase: perhaps you mean that it displays you same DAY? Since it does not display time it will display just the year, month and day so if you have 20 records added today you will see same result. Try changing formatting rule to '%M %e, %Y %H:%i:%s' and you should see the difference. Also please read my edit about giving result an alias. This may be the source of confusion if you access results improperly.

Comment: no every single record displays same date/time - the time i run the query. I know the records keep the creation date/time as I can see them when it lists the 1331865096 or 1331891838 etc. I just need to convert those long number strings into readable date.

Comment: Just uploaded image to explain results - all dates display as query time - NOT record creation time.

Comment: It is pulling out time of query and not date at all?

Comment: Well this is puzzling... you sure you are not using a query like this:
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),'%h:%i:%s'); This would be the only reason why it shows you current time - if you tell it to use UNIX_TIMESTAMP() as source...

Comment: It is strange I agree. My exact query..

`SELECT a.ID, FROM_UNIXTIME(a.time, '%M %e, %Y') as formatted_date, a.quote, a.quantity, a.media, a.print, a.pack, a.delivery, a.username, a.email, a.company, a.contact_number, a.found_us, a.additional_info, b.value AS PackDesc, c.value AS MediaDesc, d.value AS PrintDesc, e.value AS DeliveryDesc FROM wp_quotes a

INNER JOIN wp_quote_forms_fields_values b ON b.ID = a.pack
INNER JOIN wp_quote_forms_fields_values c ON c.ID = a.media
INNER JOIN wp_quote_forms_fields_values d ON d.ID = a.print
INNER JOIN wp_quote_forms_fields_values e ON e.ID = a.delivery`

Comment: any ideas? i am stuck and may have to pull the plug soon! argh.

Comment: Sorry man, but all looks OK to me. No more ideas :(. Perhaps start it as a separate question, maybe someone smarter will have some clue. Well actually try putting time in backticks like this `a.\`time\`` Perhaps your system recognizes it as current time request and not a field name??

Comment: Well there you go. The back ticks worked like a charm! Huge thank you for all your help on this. Much appreciated!

Comment: My pleasure :) Learned something myself in the process :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [FROM_UNIXTIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) to do this:

```
SELECT a.ID, FROM_UNIXTIME(a.time, '%M %e, %Y'), 
       a.quote, a.quantity, a.media, a.print, a.pack 
FROM quotes a
```

You can format a date any way you would want using the format specifies that work with [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

Comment: Unfortunately these suggestions list every record as having the same date/time - the time i run the query - not the time the records were created.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(a.`time`), '%M %e, %Y') AS `time`...
```

Refer to [MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) for the full list of DATE_FORMAT possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to use the [`FROM_UNIXTIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) function. From the documentation:

> Returns a representation of the unix_timestamp argument as a value in
>   `'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'` or `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.uuuuuu` format, depending on
>   whether the function is used in a string or numeric context.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.ID, FROM_UNIXTIME(a.time), a.quote, a.quantity, a.media, a.print, a.pack 
FROM quotes a
```

Answer (score 0):

Your can use DATE_FORMAT function likes this,

```
    SELECT a.ID, DATE_FORMAT(a.time, '%M %D %Y'), a.quote, a.quantity, a.media,a.print,a.pack 
    FROM quotes a
```